# I used pow() function in my C program but did not link to -lm it still worked. Why?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I was reading a book on GCC. It said only the standard library is linked by default for any C program. Since the `pow()` is not in the standard library, I will have to link to it using the `-lm` flag. However, when I compiled, I simply used:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

and it still worked..

And there is another similar problem, the book also said that if you have `printf("%f\n", 4);` in your C program and if you compile WITHOUT `-Wall` option, no warning will be issued. However, I tried compiling it without the `-Wall` option but I still got a warning:

> hello.c:6:2: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’,
>   but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

Why is this? The book said I have to supply `-lm` and `-Wall` in order to make my program compiled and get the warning but I did not use either of them but I still got my program compiled and got the warning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC supplies several standard library functions as [built-ins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

> GCC provides a large number of built-in functions other than the ones mentioned above. Some of these are for internal use in the processing of exceptions or variable-length argument lists and will not be documented here because they may change from time to time; we do not recommend general use of these functions.
>
> The remaining functions are provided for optimization purposes.

If you look at the list of built-ins, you'll see that `pow` is one of them.

If you add [`-fno-builtin`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno_002dbuiltin-107) to your compiler options, you should get the linker error that you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I installed the gmp package as well. The documentation also says I need to link to -lgmp in order to make it usable. However, after adding -fno-builtin, I got an error on the pow() function, but I still did not get any error or warning on using a type defined in gmp (mpz_t). Could you explain this to me as well? Thank you.

Comment: @ZesenHuang: Are you using any functions from gmp? The linker doesn't care about types.

Comment: Thank you you are absolutely right. But this is really troublesome. The book says you need the option otherwise it won't work, but the GCC itself does it for you. Is there a reason in here? Or I should ask, when I use pow() in the future, do I need to supply the -lm option? GCC does it for me already, but am I better off supply it myself?

Comment: @ZesenHuang yes you'd better supply it yourself.

Comment: Thank you, but may I ask why?

Comment: @ZesenHuang: There is a `pow` built-in for optimization purposes, the compiler will know things about the local environment that it can use to speed up an inlined `pow`. There are circumstances where a built-in won't be used and then you'll need `-lm`; there are also compilers which aren't gcc, they'll want `-lm`.

Comment: @muistooshort: Compilers other than gcc won't necessarily require, or even recognize, `-lm`. Microsoft's compiler, for example, uses a different syntax to specify libraries.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Every unix compiler I've used would understand `-lm` so maybe we should consider it shorthand for "link with the standard math library".

Answer (score 7):

A bit more information based on some experimentation.

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
#ifdef CONSTANT
    double x = pow(2.0, 10.0);
#else
    double expon = 10.0;
    double x = pow(2.0, expon);
#endif
    printf("x = %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu, when I compile it with

```
$ gcc c.c -o c
```

it complains about an undefined reference to `pow`; adding `-lm` corrects it.

But this:

```
$ gcc -DCONSTANT c.c -o c
```

compiles and links without error, replacing the `pow()` call with a constant `1024.0`.  But this:

```
$ gcc -fno-builtin -DCONSTANT c.c -o c
```

complains again about the undefined reference to `pow`.

Conclusion: gcc uses the built-in implementation of `pow` only when the result can be determined at compile time. Otherwise it generates an explicit call to the `pow()` function, which requires linking with `-lm`.

Note also that this depends on the way the C library is organized (the library is provided separately; it's not part of gcc). On Cygwin, which uses [newlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newlib) rather than the [glibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glibc) used on Ubuntu, the `-lm` option is not needed; apparently the math routines are an integral part of the standard library rather than being provided separately. (gcc on Cygwin still accepts the `-lm` option.)